# What is 'theme' / 'classes'?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am making a **react** web-application.

Trying to use **material-ui@next** for the user interface.

I am going through the demo of material-ui@next, (such as https://material-ui-next.com/demos/app-bar/ )

Every example demo code is using "theme" or "classes" and I want to know what role they are playing in any of the demo codes given.

**theme, classes** are used like below

```
const styles = theme => ({
root: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 1300,
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3, <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
},
.
.
.
.

 render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props; <<<<<<<<<<<< classes / theme here
    const { drawer_location, open } = this.state;
.
.
.
.
App.propTypes = {
classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired, }
```

I would be really appreciated if you can explain how and why they are being used in actual applications.

My guess is that these theme and classes are being passed to the current component from the parent component. If then, why are these material-ui demo codes using those ? ? ? ( There is only one component ). .

And where can I learn how to make a use of this "classes" / "theme" ??!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the following link:

https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#themes

Comment: Yes! Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these examples, `classes` is a property that is added to your component when the [withStyles](https://material-ui-next.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles) HOC is used to provide the CSS class names of the styles you've defined in code.

`withStyles` can accept an object:

```js
const styles = {
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
  },
};
```

...or a function, in cases where you need access to the material-ui theme object:

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
});
```

Here is an example of using `withStyles` with a component named `App`:

```js
export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

`withStyles` accepts your styles object (or function) and returns a function that accepts a component. The component you provide to the resulting function will be decorated with a `classes` prop.  The `classes` prop is an object that maps the class names specified in `styles` with the actual names that have are defined in the document.

Please review the docs on using [CSS in JS](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/), [overriding CSS classes](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes), and [the usage of withStyles](https://material-ui-next.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles).